# Selecting a table row to have a click event includes the children in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a table row that contains a link in it.  I set the entire row to one link and in Chrome the row goes to the link I set it to and the child link takes the user to the correct link.  in Firefox both the row and the child go to the link that is set on the row.  How can I get this to be consistent in both Firefox and Chrome.  I am setting the row to go to the link by using the following jquery

```
$('.table tbody tr, !a').click(function () {
    $.pjax({
        url: $(this).find('td a.row-click').attr('href'),
        container: '#update_panel'
    });
});
```

And the row's html looks like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Main Tire Set
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="js-pjax" href="/Events/TireSets?tireGroupID=d09fb958-d008-e211-aa97-d067e53b2ed6">Sets</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="js-pjax" href="/Events/TireBuilder?tireSetGroupID=d09fb958-d008-e211-aa97-d067e53b2ed6">Tire List</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/Events/DeleteTireGroup?tireGroupID=d09fb958-d008-e211-aa97-d067e53b2ed6"><ins class="icon-remove"></ins></a>
    </td>
    <td style="display: none;">
        <a class="row-click" href="/Events/TireInfoListView?tireSetGroupID=d09fb958-d008-e211-aa97-d067e53b2ed6">Details</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are the href for all of them the same? Why not just hard code this into your js?

Comment: each row is different,but that part works.  It is the delete button that doesn't work in firefox, though it works great in chrome.

Comment: CAN YOU make use of the `data` attribute? if so, replace the href with `javascript:void(0)` which will keep the link itself from going anywhere and place in an attribute `data-rel="www.google.com"` and then get that link from your jquery call as `.data("rel")`

Comment: I'm not sure how data attributes will fix the problem.

Comment: Open the following JSFiddle in Chrome and Firefox to see what I mean.  http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/kVUZT/2/  When in chrome and you click the delete button it only fires off the call to go to www.google.com and when it firefox it fires off a request to go to www.bing.com and then www.google.com.  Pull up the consoles to see the errors it throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to check in the click function if it was a row.  i.e.

```
$('.table tbody tr').click(function (event) {
    if (event.target.localName == 'td') {
        $.pjax({
            url: $(this).find('td a.row-click').attr('href'),
            container: '#update_panel'
        });
    }
});
```